# Python: why am I getting a NameError?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
from crypt import crypt
import itertools
from string import ascii_letters, digits

def decrypt(all_hashes, salt, charset=ascii_letters + digits + "-"):
     products = (itertools.product(charset, repeat=r) for r in range(8))
     chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(products)
     for candidate in chain:
         hash = crypt(candidate, salt)
         if hash in all_hashes:
              yield candidate, hash
              all_hashes.remove(hash)
              if not all_hashes:
                 return

all_hashes = 'aaRrt6qwqR7xk', 'aaacT.VSMxhms' , 'aaWIa93yJI9kU', /
'aakf8kFpfzD5E', 'aaMOPiDnXYTPE', 'aaz71s8a0SSbU', 'aa6SXFxZJrI7E', /
'aa9hi/efJu5P.', 'aaBWpr07X4LDE', 'aaqwyFUsGMNrQ', 'aa.lUgfbPGANY', /
'aaHgyDUxJGPl6', 'aaTuBoxlxtjeg', 'aaluQSsvEIrDs', 'aajuaeRAx9C9g', /
'aat0FraNnWA4g', 'aaya6nAGIGcYo', 'aaya6nAGIGcYo', 'aawmOHEectP/g', /
'aazpGZ/jXGDhw', 'aadc1hd1Uxlz.', 'aabx55R4tiWwQ', 'aaOhLry1KgN3.', /
'aaGO0MNkEn0JA', 'aaGxcBxfr5rgM', 'aa2voaxqfsKQA', 'aahdDVXRTugPc', /
'aaaLf47tEydKM', 'aawZuilJMRO.w', 'aayxG5tSZJJHc', 'aaPXxZDcwBKgo', /
'aaZroUk7y0Nao', 'aaZo046pM1vmY', 'aa5Be/kKhzh.o', 'aa0lJMaclo592', /
'aaY5SpAiLEJj6', 'aa..CW12pQtCE', 'aamVYXdd9MlOI', 'aajCM.48K40M.', /
'aa1iXl.B1Zjb2', 'aapG.//419wZU'


all_hashes = set(all_hashes)
salt = 'aa'
for candidate, hash in decrypt(all_hashes, salt):
     print 'Found', hash, '! The original string was', candidate
```

And when I go to run it i get the following traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in decrypt
NameError: must be string, not tuple
```

I think it has something to do with my "all_hashes" variable but if I take out the commas all the different hashes are stored as one long string

Someone please shed some light, thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean to use a backward slash, not a forward slash, for line continuation in `all_hashes`. Really though, the pythonic way to do it is to surround the values with parentheses, in which case you can break on commas *without* using line continuation.

Comment: OK thanks, have changed my code to make it more "pythonic"

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, what does `import sys; print sys.version` return?

Answer (score 3):

The `product`s are tuples, like

```
('g', 'g', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'f')
```

and `crypt` expects a string.

Transform your tuples to strings before passing them to `crypt`,

```
 for candidate in chain:
     hash = crypt((''.join(candidate)), salt)
```

(thanks to [Joel Cornett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142167/joel-cornett) for the nice transformation to string and to [HVNSweeting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807703/hvnsweeting) for the improvement on that.)

Comment: I won't deny that. Haven't got far in understanding Python error messages.

Comment: so if I take the commas out inbetween the hashes it should work?

Comment: No, you must transform your `candidate` tuples to strings before passing them to crypt, @LWH91.

Comment: I do that by using "print " ".join", but where should i put it? @DanielFischer

Comment: I'm sure there must be a better way, but `s = ""; for c in candidate: s += c` does it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do `(''.join(c) for c in candidate)`.

Comment: where do i put that? @JoelCornett

Comment: @JoelCornett Thanks. I knew there was a better way.

Comment: @LWH91 Added that to the answer.

Comment: thanks for all your help, is there a program I can use to easily edit python code? When ever I change my code I have problems with indent errors

Comment: I think ``‘’.join(candidate)`` is better if you make sure all c are strings.

Comment: @LWH91 what editor are you using? Make sure to config your editor to convert from tab to 4 spaces.

Comment: @LWH91 Any editor that is configured to never insert tabs should do fine. If all are spaces, what looks correctly indented _is_ correctly indented.

Comment: well usually I write the code using pyscripter on windows but havent really found one for unix that I like so try and do it using the simple text editor. As you can probably guess I dont use Ubuntu that often

Comment: @LWH91 I've never used it (I'm a kwrite guy), but you could try Eric (a Python IDE).

Comment: OK thanks, will try it. Seem to have the indents right now, just used the 4 spaces that was said above. thanks for all your help, hopefully it will work now, when i paste the code into the terminal will it run straight away? I was expecting to call the function but the python prompt hasn't appeared

Comment: Don't paste the code into the terminal if you have it in a file. `python yourfile.py` should run the top-level commands in the file. You can also `from yourfile import what_you_need` at the prompt of the python shell, but that also runs the top-level commands every time, so it would be a good idea to guard them with a `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the file.

Comment: so I need to make a directory called python then save my file as a .py? or do you mean to save it as a .py then type python <file>.py in the terminal?

Comment: You can save your files in any directory you want, one named Python wouldn't be a bad choice for the top level. `.py` is the canonical extension for Python source, so that would satisfy the principle of least surprise. Then you can run them from a shell in the same directory as the file is in directly with `python yourfile.py`, from other directories if you give the path to the file. If you start the file with a shebang `#! /usr/bin/env python` and make it executable, you can also run it with plain `./<file>.py`.

Comment: ive saved it on my desktop and in the terminal have just changed directory to desktop and typed "python <filename>.py. is that what you mean?

Comment: Basically, yes, although I wouldn't use the desktop directory, but that's everybody's own choice.

Comment: why not the Desktop? I also made the file an exe (using chmod +x) then went ./<filename>.py and got the following error messages: 

from: can't read /var/mail/crypt
./networkSec.py: line 9: import: command not found

from: can't read /var/mail/string
./networkSec.py: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./networkSec.py: line 18: `def decrypt(all_hashes, salt, charset=ascii_letters + digits + "-"):'

Comment: I wouldn't use desktop because I don't like too many icons displayed there; as I said, everybody's own choice. When you made the file executable, did you add the shebang line at the top? If you don't tell the OS which interpreter to use, strange things happen.

Comment: its fine with me, dont really use ubuntu (as you can easily tell). I forgot to add that, added it now and it appears that nothing is happening, the cursor is just flashing on a new line, is everything good?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20024/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-lwh91)